# Matlab R2010a over ssh -X displays empty windows

Tags: debian, ssh, xorg

I'm trying to use Matlab R2010a over ssh, with X forwarding.

Now the X forwarding certainly works (for example xclock displays nice and fast)

But when invoking matlab, I get the splash screen ok, and when the desktop loads, I just get an empty window (only the start button is displayed). The window apears somewhat functional: Clicking in the area where the menu is supposed to be does open the menu.

Now the question is: how to fix this?

I'm using the [grml](http://grml.org) 2010.12 live cd (which is based on debian unstable), with xorg 1:7.5+8 and the nouveau X driver.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `vncserver` if you have port forwarding enabled on the remote host:

Connect to the remote_host:

```
$ ssh -L local_port:remote_host:5910 127.0.0.1
vncserver :10
```

Then run on the local host:

```
vncviewer 127.0.0.1:local_port
```

Replace local_port for any port number you want.